# Is there a way to ignore the field formatting of a custom field?

Tags: custom-fields

I know you can change them globally from the Admin menu, but what I was hoping for was someway to temporarily ignore the field formatting selected and simply output the data in the field.

Why? I have a bunch of Smartdown fields (Markdown) that I want to actually show the pre-parsed MD -- without actually changing the formatting of the field.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Single Field](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/single-field) - it can grab your raw data using its `field_format="raw"` parameter.

Or, just use the Query module:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT field_id_XX FROM exp_channel_data WHERE entry_id = XX"}
    {field_id_XX}
{/exp:query}
```

Comment: The Query module works great, but unfortunately I lose all line breaks. Is there any way to output raw data with those line breaks still in there?

Comment: That's odd. Do you mean spaces between paragraphs? Or manual Markdown line breaks (3 spaces)?

Comment: Spaces between paragraphs. I get the raw pre-Markdown formatted data, but it's one giant run-on sentence.

Comment: On the page, or in the source code? Try outputting it within `<pre>` tags.

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be the random case, where Derek Jones' [No Formatting](https://github.com/EllisLab/No-Formatting) might come in use. It can be used directly on the template like:

```
{exp:no_formatting}{my_field}{/exp:no_formatting}
```

And *should* return just the string of text from the field. I emphasize *should* because I've never used it with 'Markdown' in a field.

Comment: This won't work. Formatting is applied to the field before it hits the template, and the No Formatting plugin simply returns exactly the same data inside it.

Comment: Ahh… so this would almost be the same as the display code issue then, except for the field_type he's using. So, then since Markdown requires separate parsing then say, just HTML, couldn't he just change the field_type to say `textarea` and then the Markdown would be displayed. Or Derek's suggestion of 'Single Field' add-on.

Comment: Yes, that would be possible. set the fieldtype to no-formatting and use the plugin separately in the template to format markdown for the field when needed.